# What parts can be recycled when doing regular maintenance?

Tags: scheduled-maintenance, recycle

I recently changed my wiper blades... are these just garbage or would an Autozone or perhaps some mechanics recycle parts like this?

What other regularly-replaced parts can be recycled?

**EDIT:** Other regular maintenance might include air filters, oil change, tires, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change your oil, there are places that will take your used motor oil.  My Dad's shop uses used motor oil as fuel in the furnace to keep the garage warm in the winter.

I know this seems obvious to many, but it never surprises me the number of people that would just dump this stuff in the grass :(

Answer (score 2):

### Batteries

When buying a new battery, most Auto parts stores will recycle your old battery for you. For example, Autozone charges an extra $12 (or so), which is refunded to you when you return your old battery.